# Vector component of $\bar{u}$ orthogonal to $\bar{a}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\bar{u} = (3,3,-1)$ and $\bar{a} =(-3,3,-2)$

Find the vector component of $\bar{u}$ orthogonal to $\bar{a}$

Ok, so pretty straight forward I found the projection

$\bar{u}\cdot$ $\bar{a}$ = $(3*3) +(3*-3) +(-1*-2) = 2$

$||v||^{2} = \sqrt{(-3)^2+3^2+(-2)^2} = 22$

$proj = \frac{2}{22}*(-3,3,-2) = (-\frac{6}{22},\frac{6}{22},-\frac{4}{22}) $

$\bar{u}$ - $proj$ = $(3,3,−1) - (-\frac{6}{22},\frac{6}{22},-\frac{4}{22}) = (\frac{75}{22},\frac{57}{22},-\frac{9}{11})$

I am second guessing myself as this is the last attempt I have on the question. Can anyone verify my calculations?

Comment: i made an edit and corrected the square root that was not suppose to be there.

Comment: An easy way to check your answer is to see if your answer is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$ and the projection by taking the dot product. Here both of those are $0$ and the projection plus the answer is $\mathbf{u}$ so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

While you get the idea, there are careless mistake:$$proj = \frac{2}{22}(-3,3,-2) = (-\frac{\color{red}6}{22},\frac{\color{red}6}{22},-\frac{4}{22}) $$

Edit: Octave output

```
octave:10>  u - (u'*a)* a / norm(a)^2
ans =

   3.27273
   2.72727
  -0.81818
```

Comment: Ahh I was in the middle of correcting them as you posted. Thank you.

Comment: All is corrected, if you wouldn't mind taking another look

Comment: seems fine. I have included the octave output. Strange, did the answer just changed? current solution doesn't seems to be correct. Try to get numbers that matches the octave output.